# Highlight HTML in Python String

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a VSCode extension that highlights HTML code within strings?

Some of my modules include a bunch of HTML responses and I make some very simplistic mistakes at times, such as opening/closing tags, which could be helped if the entire block of text wasn't the same color.

I've found some that do this in different ways for different languages/platforms, but none for HTML in Python strings.

Comment: Do not use big html strings. You should do that using templates like jinja.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension that does that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samwillis.python-inline-source

```
html = str  # Create an alias of the str type named for the language you are using

my_html_string: html = """
  <h1>Some HTML</h1>
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the HTML string from files as an alternative to writing HTML as strings if your HTML is static.

Create HTML files and load them in as strings from the file.

Comment: why build your own template engine when there are a lot of good alternatives to use. Once he sees the benefit of templates with inheritance/extension he never wants to go back

Comment: @rioV8 Because he never mentioned dynamic content that requires templating. That is why i said he could just load *static HTML* files

Answer (score 0):

This was seriously painful to figure out and ridiculously easy to do.
Recommend making backups!

Use vscode to open:
`\Users\%userid%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\python\syntaxes\MagicPython.tmLanguage.json`

It opens as a continuous string of JSON.
Ensure JSON is the selected language mode
Right click in body of document and select "Format Document"

Find the section of code that looks like below and add ***{"include": "text.html.basic"},*** to the "**patterns**" section. (Already done in example)

```json
    "string-quoted-multi-line": {  
        "name": "string.quoted.multi.python",
            "begin": "(?:\\b([rR])(?=[uU]))?([uU])?('''|\"\"\")",
            "end": "(\\3)",
            "beginCaptures": {
                "1": {"name": "invalid.illegal.prefix.python"},
                "2": {"name": "storage.type.string.python"},
                "3": {"name": "punctuation.definition.string.begin.python"}
            },
            "endCaptures": {
                "1": {"name": "punctuation.definition.string.end.python"},
                "2": {"name": "invalid.illegal.newline.python"}
            },
            "patterns": [
                {"include": "text.html.basic"},
                {"include": "#string-multi-bad-brace1-formatting-unicode"},
                {"include": "#string-multi-bad-brace2-formatting-unicode"},
                {"include": "#string-unicode-guts"}
            ]
        },
```

Save & Exit vscode, then reopen it and open a .py file
Sometimes had to close and reopen more than once to get it to recognize changes.

HTML formatting will be applied to text inside `'''` or `"""` quoted strings that are assigned to variables
i.e. The html in the string will be formatted as html.

```html
myvar = '''
<script>
// A comment
</script>
<body>
<!-- a comment -->
</body>
'''
```

To do the same with f'strings' add the same line added to...
"fstring-fnorm-quoted-multi-line"

I noted some inconsistencies with the formatting when using fstrings but not with plain multi-quoted strings...
This entire line will be formatted as a comment `// JS Comment {myvar}`

Comment: Also recommending the answer by @parkerd as the best option.